# creating stylized backgorund

Tags: adobe-illustrator, background, layer-style

I was going through Adobe Website's official Illustrator tutorial. They have some pre-created sheets where I found this.Can someone tell me how to create this type of sylized backdrop for background as shown by the bounding box in the right side of the snapshot?[image]

Comment: Did you think of checking the Appearance panel?

Answer (score 2):

They are merely patterns available in the **Swatches Panel**... "Basic Graphic Lines" and "Basic Graphic Dots". Then it appears the opacity has been lowered after the pattern fills have been applied.

[image]